# Xamarin comonality layer for Android/iOS/WinPhone

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Xamarin / Mono-touch lets you leverage any native code / APIs on the target platform. . But is there a commonality layer, so that things like accelerometer, camera and so forth can be written using the same code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple libraires designed to be used across different platforms (available through the component store):

- **Xamarin.Mobile** to access device capabilities
- **Xamarin.Auth** to authenticate users on OAuth
- **Xamarin.Social** to access social networks

and then all the projects targeting PCL and available via nugget:

- **Json.NET**
- **HttpClient**

That should get you started. Oh, one more thing. If you use HttpClient, have a look at **ModernHttpClient** (component store)

Answer (score 3):

The Xamarin.mobile API provides this abstraction layer to access features that are typically provided on all supported platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I have added some device abstraction in my libraries. Currently Battery (level and charger status) and Accelerometer are abstracted to static classes that are 100% identical interface between iOS, Android & WP8. As time permits I will add more, including GPS.

https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile

To use serializer in PCL libraries I have created a common interface so you can use non-PCL's as well. Some of the best performing (de)serializers are not available as PCL and some aren't available on iOS at all but a common interface allows one to pick the best per platform. Some performance test results are posted on Xamarin forums: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9886/quick-json-serializer-performance-test-json-net-vs-servicestack/p1